# Process Builder - Auto Create Event after a call is logged

Tags: process-builder, event, conditional

**What I am trying to do ?**

When a Call is logged (via Log a Call), Create a follow up event automatically.

**How did I do this ?**

I created a workflow via Process Builder to auto Create Events when a call is logged .

[image: Process Builder - Workflow to Create Event]

**What is my problem?**

I have defined the Event StartDate and EndDate in the formula. As a result, users have no control over selecting the Event Start and End Date.

Users should be able to pick the Start and End date before Saving the 'Log a Call'

**The solutions I thought -**

Option 1. IF Result__c = 'Demo' Show StartDate__c and EndDate__c fields for the user to select datetime
// However I could'nt find a way to show fields conditionally using declarative approach

Option 2. If Result_c = 'Demo' open the 'Create New Event' for the user to manually create new event, instead of of the New Event getting created automaically
// Again here i am not sure how I can navigate to the 'Create New event' page via process builder

**My Question**
Is there a way to achieve solution in Option 1 declaratively?
if not, how can i semi automate the process - i.e Create Event Automatically but let users enter the Start and End date before saving the logged call?

Comment: have you looked at screen flows?

Comment: no, i haven't looked at screen flows.

Comment: In the process builder update action if you choose formula type then you can build logic using IF function.

Comment: @LironC  good suggestion! Do you have an example or point me in some direction? Thanks

Comment: So do you have the end users input the start/end time on the log a call action? The formula is only helpful if you already know what the user-defined start/end times should be versus automatically setting them.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, in that case as explained in my original question - i would go by Option 1 solution. In that case, as I have already asked in my question - is there a way for Start/End date to be made visible only if Result__c = 'Demo' , hide otherwise ?